# Sending emails with signatures via C#

Tags: c#, image, email

I have a the following setup to send emails from my c# Application :

- SmtpClient (under System.Net.Mail namespace) to do the actual sending once everything is in place and set the 'IsBodyHtml' property of the Message object to True
- Using the dll from [Sautinsoft](http://sautinsoft.net/rtf-to-html-convert.aspx/) I convert a simple rtf file which contains the formatting of the email and convert it to a HTML string which I then use as the body of the mail.

It works great just as it is and I have sent a few test emails to myself and all the appropriate formatting is retained. However i am having a problem with images - The dll converts images to a img tag and uses the base 64 format of the image as the data source, this works fine if you view it as a html page, but sending it as the body of you email produces problems. Email clients such as Yahoo don't mind embedded images but Gmail does not play nice with this methodology. The only image that should appear in the emails I'm sending is the signature image located at the bottom of each email. Using signatures in the native Gmail client in your browser poses no problems since the image has a link to a actual file on a server somewhere, but sending emails with signatures via a C# Application seems to be a different story. Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider automating Outlook from a C# application. See [How to automate Outlook and Word by using Visual C# .NET to create a pre-populated e-mail message that can be edited](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819398). Also you can find a sample code - [C# app automates Outlook (CSAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about RTF2HTML, you may add any images in a separate folder (no include in body of HTML):

```
string inpFile = @"..\..\..\..\example.docx";
        string outFile = Path.GetFullPath(@"Result2.html");
        string imgDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(outFile);

        RtfToHtml r = new RtfToHtml();

        // Set images directory
        HtmlFixedSaveOptions opt = new HtmlFixedSaveOptions()
        {
            ImagesDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(imgDir, "Result_images"),
            ImagesDirectorySrcPath = "Result_images",
            // Change to store images as physical files on local drive.
            EmbedImages = false
        };

        try
        {
            r.Convert(inpFile, outFile, opt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Conversion failed! {ex.Message}");
        }
```

As the result you will see HTML file with linked images in folder.